# Bamboo doesn't reuse ssh private key config of job repository

Tags: git, ssh, git-push, bamboo

My job consists of source checkout, incrementing version and pushing back to repository. Repository config consists of ssh private key and passphrase. Source code checkout goes ok, but pushing back fails with:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

What I have doen so far:

1) Public client is attached to github account.

2) Correctness of passphrase have been checked several times.

3) I've debugged ssh command connections with:

```
ssh -vT server
```

and received:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bamboo/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bamboo/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bamboo/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
2Permission denied (publickey).
```

which means that git or ssh command don't use key provided in repository config.

Maybe someone have faced with such an issue and have resolved it?

Comment: I vaguely recall adding my client side public key to the server's accepted keystore file manually for a home server setup. Maybe the Pro Git ebook has some helpful information?

Comment: It's completely Bamboo issue, because git push works ok on local environment with this key.

Comment: Does one of the "trying private key" debug lines reference the key that you think should be accepted by github?

Comment: Kenster, no. Those keys couldn't be accepted by github, because files don't exist.